# SQL GROUP BY and MIN in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access-2010

I want to combine 2 tables and I want to use GROUP BY and select MIN value in each field in the table
I have 2 tables: TransactionDB and Product

TransactionDB = is where the list of transactions are listed

```
 ProductName                 RemainingStocks
 --------------------------------------------  
 Euphorbia 90 capsules       100  
 Euphorbia 90 capsules       99
```

Products = lists of products

```
 ProductName                 RemainingStocks
 --------------------------------------------  
 Euphorbia 90 capsules       99  
 Lemongrass Tea              100
```

I used INSERT INTO statement to insert records from Product Table to TransactionDB Table

```
           INSERT INTO Inventory ( ProductName, RemainingStocks )
           SELECT ProductName, RemainingStocks
           FROM Product;
```

The Products Table Becomes

```
ProductName                 RemainingStocks
--------------------------------------------  
Euphorbia 90 capsules       100  
Euphorbia 90 capsules       99 
Euphorbia 90 capsules       99  
Lemongrass Tea              100
```

Used GROUP BY SELECT to group productname and MIN for the Remaining Stocks

```
               SELECT ProductName,MIN(RemainingStocks)
               FROM TransactionDB
               GROUP BY ProductName;
```

Products table becomes

```
ProductName                 Expr101
--------------------------------------------  
Euphorbia 90 capsules       100  
Euphorbia 90 capsules       99   
Lemongrass Tea              100
```

I Want it Like this...Help

```
ProductName                 RemainingStocks
--------------------------------------------   
Euphorbia 90 capsules       99   
Lemongrass Tea              100
```

Comment: You want an UPDATE istead of INSERT. But I think this is a bad design. It's generally a bad idea to store computed values like that, you can easily get inconsistent data if somebody makes a mistake. Create a view instead, that always returns the up to date values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer.What do you mean by "Create a view instead"?

Comment: Hasn't Access got views? It's like a pre-defined select, which can include calculations.